# Writing a foldMap in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functor, foldable

I am trying to write my own foldMap function as an excersice to learn Haskell

Currently it looks like this

```
class Functor f => Foldable f where
    fold    :: Monoid m =>             f m -> m
    foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> f a -> m
    foldMap g a = fold (<>) mempty (fmap g a)
```

However when compiling it it gives the following error

```
Could not deduce (Monoid ((f m -> m) -> fm -> m)) arising from use of 'fold'
from the context (Foldable f) bound by the class declaration for 'Foldable' at (file location)
or from (Monoid m) bound by the type signature for foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> f a -> m at (file location
In the expression fold (<>) mempty (fmap g a)
In an equation for 'foldMap':
     foldMap g a = fold (<>) mempty (fmap g a)
```

I can't figure out what the compiler is trying to tell me with this error, can anyone tell me what goes wrong with my foldMap?

Comment: `fold` has one argument but you are supplying three.

Comment: @Lee: to repeat the old mantra – _every_ function has just one argument. `fold` can actually have quite realistically extra curry arguments, e.g. with the `a -> Ordering` monoid – though I'm pretty sure that doesn't apply to the OP's case.

Comment: you just have indeed **to much** in there ;) ... all the right parts are there put you have to *remove* some ;)

Comment: -facepalm- I was confusing the fold method with the foldr method, which does have two extra curry arguments, but the fold method does not, thanks for the help guys!

Comment: @Lee: You could turn that into an answer so that the question is marked as answered.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe we should do an answer with the actual solution:

I hope it's now clear, that this is a possible definition:

```
class Functor f => Foldable f where
    fold    :: Monoid m =>             f m -> m
    foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> f a -> m
    foldMap g a = fold $ fmap g a
```

#### follow the types

Andrew and Lee already gave you a high level explanation but maybe I can give you another view on it:

Let's just *follow the types* to oget to this answer:

We want a function `f a -> m` where `m` is a monoid and `f` is a functor. In addition we have a function `g :: a -> m` we can use to get from some `a` into the monoid - nice.

Now we get some additional functions:

- `fold :: f m -> m` from our own class
- `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` from the Functor `f`

Ok we need `f a -> m` now if only the `a` would be an `m` then we could use `fold` ... dang.

But wait: we can make a `a` into a `m` using `g`- but the `a` is packed into `f` ... dang.

Oh wait: we can make a `f a` into a `f m` using `fmap` .... ding-ding-ding

So let's do it:

- make `f a` into `f m`: `fmap g a`
- use fold on it: `fold (fmap g a)`

or using `$`:

```
foldMap g a = fold $ fmap g a
```

#### example

Let's get something so we can try:

```
module Foldable where

import Data.Monoid

class Functor f => Foldable f where
    fold    :: Monoid m => f m -> m
    foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> f a -> m
    foldMap g a = fold $ fmap g a

instance Foldable [] where
  fold []     = mempty
  fold (x:xs) = mappend x (fold xs)
```

here is a simple example using this with `Sum` and `[1..4]`:

```
λ> foldMap Sum [1..4]
Sum {getSum = 10}
```

which seems fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

A Monoid has two functions, `mappend` and `mempty`, and you can use `(<>)` in place of `mappend`.

Typeclasses work because the compiler inserts the appropriate definition for the function depending on the types of the data, so (happily) there's no need to pass around the function in question.

The mistake you've made is to unnecessarily pass the Monoid functions you're using in.

For example, if I defined a function to test if something was in a list like this:

```
isin :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
isin equalityFunction a list = any (equalityFunction a) list
```

I'd have unnecessarily tried to pass the `equalityFunction` as an argument, and the type signature doesn't match it.

Instead I should define

```
isin :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
isin a list = any (== a) list
```

using the standard name for the equality function as defined in the `Eq` typeclass.

Similarly, you neither need nor should pass the `(<>)` or `empty` arguments.